# How can I collect a list of ST actions inside Either?

Tags: haskell

How can I go about converting an `[Either ST]` to an `Either [ST]` and subsequently run the actions sequentially? The below code appears to work for running a list of ST actions, however when trying to generate the list of actions in Either (swapping the `test` definitions below) the types no longer line up. I would have expected the types of the lists to be identical so I would greatly appreciate any explanation of the differences.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import qualified Data.STRef as ST
import qualified Control.Monad.ST as ST

run :: (forall s. [ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int]) -> Int
run fs =
  ST.runST $ do
    x <- ST.newSTRef 0
    mapM_ (\f ->
        f x >>= ST.writeSTRef x
      ) fs
    ST.readSTRef x

action :: ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int
action = \x -> ST.readSTRef x >>= \y -> return (y + 1)

-- test :: Either String Int
-- test = mapM (const (return action)) [0..5] >>= \fs -> return (run fs)

test :: Int
test = run (map (const action) [0..5])

main = print test
```

Comment: [**`sequence`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=sequence)?

Comment: @recursion.ninja that's an excellent suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't appear to make a difference. Would you expect there to be instances of `sequence` having different results than `mapM`?

Comment: I'm formulating an answer now

Comment: Write `E` as an abbreviation for `Either String`, and `x` for `[STRef s Int -> ST s Int]`. My guess is that `(>>=)` is being inferred to have type `forall s. E x -> (x -> E Int) -> E Int`, when you wanted it to be inferred as having type `E (forall s. x) -> ((forall s. x) -> E Int) -> E Int`. A similar type-variable scoping issue applies to the other combinators (`mapM`, `const`, `return`). Since this wanders into impredicative type territory, you're going to have a nasty time to get this working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type inference in the presence of higher-rank types is undecidable. GHC's type inference algorithm makes some simplifying assumptions, which render it incomplete. Those include:

- GHC will assume the variable bound by a lambda is a monotype (it does not contain (leading?) `forall`s)
- When you use a polymorphic function, GHC will assume that the free type variables in its type will be instantiated at monotypes

Both of these assumptions can be overridden if you ask GHC politely to use a particular polytype instead.

Now, how do you expect your program to type check?

- In order for `run fs` to type check, we had better have `fs :: forall s. [ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int]`
- So, according to the first point above we must write this type signature on the lambda that binds it: `\(fs :: forall s. [ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int]) -> ...` (using `ScopedTypeVariables`)
- Now consider the use of `>>=`. Its type is `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. But, we need `a = forall s. [ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int]`. So, according to the second point above we need to give this `>>=` a type signature, as in

  ```
  ... `op` (\(fs :: forall s. [ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int]) -> ...)
      where op :: Monad m
               => m (forall s. [ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int])
               -> ((forall s. [ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int]) -> m b)
               -> m b
            op = (>>=)
  ```
- Now we run into a new kind of problem. In this application of `op`, the first argument has type `Either String (forall s. [ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int])`. Application of a type constructor (other than `(->)`) to a polytype is not allowed, unless you turn on the (broken) ImpredicativeTypes. However, we can turn it on and continue...
- Diving into the first argument, we can see that we will need `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` instantiated at `a = forall s. ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int`. So, we need to add another type signature to `return`
- Similarly we will need `mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]` instantiated at `b = forall s. ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int`
- If you are paying close attention you will notice yet another problem: the result of the `mapM` has type

  ```
  Either String [forall s. ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int]
  ```

  but the argument of `(>>=)` needs to be of type

  ```
  Either String (forall s. [ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int])
  ```

  and you will need to convert between these. In reality this is a no-op, but GHC is not smart enough to know it, so you will have to do a linear-time conversion, something like

  ```
  liftM (\x -> map (\(y :: forall s. ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int) -> y) x)
  ```

  (except `liftM` will need yet another type signature)

Moral of the story: You can do this, but you shouldn't.

You will generally have an easier time if you hide your `forall`s inside newtypes like

```
newtype S s = S { unS :: forall s. ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int }
```

which makes the points where polymorphism is introduced more explicit in your program (via occurrences of `S` and `unS`).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was hoping for this kind of explanation that I might develop a better intuition for the type checking process. I still need to read through this many more times but it has been extremely helpful!

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap the functions in a `newtype` to preserve the existential quantification without having to use `ImpredicativeTypes`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import qualified Data.STRef as ST
import qualified Control.Monad.ST as ST

newtype STFunc = STFunc (forall s. ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int)

run :: [STFunc] -> Int
run fs = ST.runST $ do
    x <- ST.newSTRef 0
    mapM_ (\(STFunc f) ->
        f x >>= ST.writeSTRef x
      ) fs
    ST.readSTRef x

action :: STFunc
action = STFunc $ \x -> ST.readSTRef x >>= \y -> return (y + 1)

test :: Either String Int
test = mapM (const (return action)) [0..5] >>= \fs -> return (run fs)

main = print test
```

Comment: Fascinating! I have so much to learn. I am curious since you mentioned `ImpredicativeTypes` how it would be solvable using that extension? I had actually experimented with turning that on, but was unable to determine the correct incantation.

Comment: You probably mean a _universal_, not an _existential_ quantification here.

Comment: @ZJM Impredicative types basically allow to construct types for the form `T (forall a. ...)` such as your `[forall s. ...]`, without resorting to a newtype and `[STFunc]` as above. However, they tend to require type annotations in many inconvenient places.

Comment: @ZJM A possible working incantation is `type STFunc = forall s. ST.STRef s Int -> ST.ST s Int` and then `test = mapM (const ((return :: STFunc -> Either String STFunc) action )) [0..5] >>= \fs -> return (run fs)`. You'll have to adapt the rest as well, but it should be straightforward to remove the newtype and use the type synonym instead. Anyway, I'd not recommend impredicative types, but feel free to play around with them.